# Bundler Capistrano question: How does Rails know where my gems are?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, capistrano, bundler

I'm using the standard bundler/capistrano recipe that installs all necessary gems on the server `after deploy:update_code`

Works like a charm and has simplified my life significantly.

I'm using Rails 2.3.10 and 'patched' the boot.rb and created the preinitializer as was necessary.

My question is, how does Rails know that my gems reside in the shared/bundle directory, and how does it know to use these?  Is this directory somehow automatically added to the load path?  How do these gems take precedent over system gems?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

jdl, thanks for the heads up on where to look.  Here's my understanding of what happens.

Bundler automatically installs the gems into shared/bundle, as specified using `bundle_dir` from the Gemfile, it defaults to this:

```
# (line 39 bundler/deployment.rb)
set :bundle_dir, File.join(fetch(:shared_path), 'bundle')
```

`:shared_path` comes from capistrano

So that's step one of installing the gems.  Now, as far as I understand, when you specify a directory to install gems into, Bundler always modifies the `.bundle/config` in the root dir (ie where the `Gemfile` is located).  This is what mine looks like after doing that bundle install to the shared dir:

```
--- 
BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: "1"
BUNDLE_WITHOUT: development:test
BUNDLE_FROZEN: "1"
BUNDLE_PATH: /mnt/apps/my_app/shared/bundle
```

Then, (as pointed out by jdl) the GEM_HOME gets set based off this .bundle/config.

The method `configure_gem_home_and_path` in `bundler.rb` sets `ENV['GEM_HOME']` and it's based off of some settings, that, through a convoluted process end up getting the `BUNDLE_PATH` from your .bundle/config.

whew...

Answer (score 0):

The `GEM_HOME` environment variable is what you're looking for.

[Docs are here.](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/12)

Comment: but my question is... how is GEM_HOME pointing to my shared/bundle directory, which I've never explicitly set this.  I'm assuming Bundler does some magic, but I can't see where.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have more time for this. Look in `bundler.rb` in the Bundler gem. You should find something in there that modifies `GEM_HOME` and `GEM_PATH`. Trace that code, and I'll bet you find where it's grabbing the gems you're referring to.

Comment: see my post below, think i got it answered

Comment: I think this answer is not related to capistrano but general bundler usage